# Paging and Filter in Yii2 Gridview

Tags: gridview, filter, pagination, yii2

I used the CRUD generator in Yii2 and it generated the following code for my `actionIndex` controller...

```php
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new LeadSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

I am trying to do two things to this default code:

1) Set the page size so that the gridview displaying it only shows 10 rows

2) Modify the `$searchModel` such that it only returns records where the status column in the table matches certain multiple values (IN Operator)... or better yet, all records that don't match a given value.

For #1, I see many examples to set the 'pagination' while using `ActiveDataProvider`, but none for `search()`. This code didn't work for me...

```php
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(
    Yii::$app->request->queryParams, ['pagination' => [ 'pageSize' => 10 ]]
);
```

For #2, I know we can filter by declaring the new LeadSearch object as...

```php
$searchModel = new LeadSearch([ 'status' => 'open' ]);
```

...but something like this doesn't work...

```php
$searchModel = new LeadSearch([ 'status' => ['open', 'pending'] ]);
```

Comment: Your first question maybe can be answered here [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23336269/how-to-create-pager-in-yii2) and I guess you can add this query filter in the `$query` object inside the search_model. Add some `$query->andWhere([ 'status' => ['open', 'pending'] ])`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add `pagination` option in `ActiveDataProvider` in search model and also put `where` or `andWhere` at `$query` condition.

```php
$query = modalName::find()->andWhere([ 'status' => ['open', 'pending'] ]);

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => [ 'pageSize' => 10 ],
        ]);
```

Comment: how can we set pagination in gridview on views page rather than in controller

Comment: added this but pagination is still not visible in `GridView` in yii2

Answer (score 6):

```
    $searchModel = new PersonSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(
    Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->pagination = ['pageSize' => 10,];
```

Answer (score 2):

Following Yii's [getting started tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-databases), ***$dataProvider*** has a ***setPagination*** method.

```
...
/** Basic generated code from Gii **/
$searchModel = new AlbumSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

/** Paginate & Show 5 items in the table */
$dataProvider->setPagination(['pageSize' => 5]); 
...
```

The [top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32493005/7870472) is excessive because it creates a `new ActiveDataProvider(...)` and re-inserts its own `query` just to set the pagination. Please be guided.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
$dataProvider->pagination = ['pageSize' => 10];
```

Comment: Don't post code as images in the answers. It is not necessary. Stack Overflow can display code properly, and it's more useful if it's just text.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.